# Ansible playbook-wide variable

Tags: variables, ansible

I have a playbook with multiple hosts section. I would like to define a variable in this playbook.yml file that applies only within the file, for example:

```
vars:
  my_global_var: 'hello'

- hosts: db
  tasks:
   -shell: echo {{my_global_var}} 

- hosts: web
  tasks:
   -shell: echo {{my_global_var}}
```

The example above does not work. I have to either duplicate the variable for each host section (bad) or define it at higher level, for example in my `group_vars/all` (not what I want, but works). I am also aware that variables files can be included, but this affects readibility. Any suggestion to get it in the right scope (e.g the playbook file itself)?

Comment: You may be interested in PR [#13787](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/13787) which implements exactly what you're looking for (and also playbook-wide vars_prompt).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `set_fact` module will accomplish this if group_vars don't suit your needs.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html

> This module allows setting new variables. Variables are set on a host-by-host >basis just like facts discovered by the setup module. These variables will >survive between plays during an Ansible run, but will not be saved across >executions even if you use a fact cache.

```
- hosts: db:web
  tasks:
  - set_fact: my_global_var='hello'

- hosts: db
  tasks:
  -shell: echo {{my_global_var}} 

- hosts: web
  tasks:
  -shell: echo {{my_global_var}}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me with Ansible 2.8. Any ideas?

Comment: Working for me in Ansible 2.10.5.

Answer (score 7):

I prefer to keep global variables in the inventory file, where you keep the groups and names of your hosts.

For example:

`my-hosts`:

```
[all:vars]
my_global_var="hello"

[db]
db1
db2
[web]
web1
web2
```

Run your playbook with:

```
ansible-playbook -i my-hosts playbook.yml
```

The variable will now be defined for all hosts.

If you are using `ec2.py` or some other [dynamic inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html), you can put the global variables in the file `group_vars/all` to achieve the same result.

Comment: As I mentioned, putting the var in the inventory or host file works, but is harder to read then defining it in the playbook, as you have to look at 2 or more files.

Comment: You didn't actually mention the inventory in your question, which is why I suggested it :-) Since this is a file you must use anyway, to define your hosts, it makes sense to define your variables there too.

Comment: What about when you're using dynamic inventory like ec2.py?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @xenithorb. When using a dynamic inventory you can put the global vars in `group_vars/all` instead. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar, several variables that are dependent on one, possibly user-specified, variable, that is used in most of my plays (referring to a directory where stuff is). This can be done using one file that contains the plays using the var, and another containing a single play that sets the var and includes the play. EG:

```
- name: Set global vars, import playbook that uses them
  import_playbook: do-stuff.yml
  vars:
    my_var: with_value
    some_var: "{{ my_var}}"
```

Here, some_var and my_var can be accessed by all plays in the do-stuff.yml, and the user can overwrite my_var if desired.